# Canvas and unit/normal gradients

Tags: math, html5-canvas, gradient, linear-gradients

I am trying to use unit/normal vector based gradients in html5 canvas element and transform them afterwards for the desired results. However, I seem to figure troubles which might be because of my lack of math. I am trying to create a simple linear gradient going from 0,0 to 1,0 (i.e. a simple unit gradient going from left to right). Afterwards, I transform the canvas for scaling, rotating and moving the gradient. However, when for example giving a rotation value of 45DEG, the actual gradient gets painted wrong. The right bottom corner has way to much black that is, the gradient seems to be not "big" enough. Here's my code:

```
var rect = {x: 0, y: 0, w: 500, h: 500};
var rotation = 45 * Math.PI/180;
var sx = 1;
var sy = 1;
var tx = 0;
var ty = 0;
var radial = false;

// Create unit vector 0,0 1,1
var grd = radial ? ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5) : ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, 'black');
grd.addColorStop(0.1, 'lime');
grd.addColorStop(0.9, 'yellow');
grd.addColorStop(1, 'black');

// Add our rectangle path before transforming
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(rect.x, rect.y);
ctx.lineTo(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y);
ctx.lineTo(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h);
ctx.lineTo(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h);
ctx.closePath();

// Rotate and scale unit gradient
ctx.rotate(rotation);
ctx.scale(sx * rect.w, sy * rect.h);
ctx.fillStyle = grd;

// Fill gradient
ctx.fill();
```

And here's the fiddle to try it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/4GsCE/1/

Curious enough, changing the unit linear gradient vector to a factor of about 1.41 makes the gradient look right:

```
ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 1.41, 0)
```

Which can be seen in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4GsCE/2/

But I couldn't figure how to calculate that factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use normalized gradients, you have to decide how to normalize. Here you choose to center the gradient, and to have its (x,y) in the [-0.5, 0.5 ] range.
First issue is that the linear gradient is not centered, it's in the [0, 1.0] range.
Normalize them the same way :

```
var linGrd = ctx.createLinearGradient(-0.5, 0, 0.5, 0);
```

Second issue is that you must *translate* to the center of your figure, then scale, then draw in a normalized way.
Meaning you must use same coordinate system as your gradients.
Since you were both drawing a shape having (w,h) as size AND using a scale of (w,h), you were drawing a ( w*w, h*h ) sized rect.
Correct draw code is this one :

```
function drawRect(rect, fill) {
    ctx.save();
    // translate to the center of the rect (the new (0,0) )
    ctx.translate(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y + rect.h / 2);
    // Rotate 
    ctx.rotate(rotation);
    // scale to the size of the rect
    ctx.scale(rect.w, rect.h);
    // ...
    ctx.fillStyle = fill;
    // draw 'normalized' rect
    ctx.fillRect(-0.5, -0.5, 1, 1);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Notice that by default the radialGradient will end at a distance of 0.5, meaning, if you are filling a rect, that it will fill the corners with the last color of the gradient. Maybe you want the corners to end the gradient.
In that case, you want to have the gradient to reach its value at a distance of :

```
sqrt ( 0.5*0.5 + 0.5*0.5 ) = 0.7  ( pythagore in the normalized circle)
```

So you'll define your normalized gradient like :

```
var fullRadGrd = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7) ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/4GsCE/4/

[image]

Comment: Wow, great answer. Actually, just a couple of mins ago I've figured the center issue of the linear gradient myself :)